# XM to JSON using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have to transform XML to JSON using XSLT and I have not that much idea on the same..Please any one help. JSON is new for me, I have done XML to XML or CSV.

```
 INPUT :
      <RU>
<HU>
    <WS>COA</WS>               
    <WS-TA>02641</WS-TA>               
    <WS-TAG>2019-02-15</WS-TAG> 
    <WS-TAG-CU>2019-02-16-01.35.15.906470</WS-TAG-CU>          
    <WS-TAG-OCC>006</WS-TAG-OCC>      
</HU>
<DU>
    <WS-TAG-CO>001</WS-TAG-CO>           
    <WS-TAG-NO-PA/>
    <WS-TAG-NO-PART-BA>1234</WS-TAG-NO-PART-BA>            
    <WS-TAG-NO-PART-PR>ABC2</WS-TAG-NO-PART-PR>          
    <WS-TAG-NO-PART-SUF>PA</WS-TAG-NO-PART-SUF>             
    <WS-TAG-NOY/>         
</DU>
<DU>
    <WS-TAG-CO>002</WS-TAG-CO>        
    <WS-TAG-NO-PA/>
    <WS-TAG-NO-PART-BA>000V23</WS-TAG-NO-PART-BA>
    <WS-TAG-NO-PART-PR>P1W2</WS-TAG-NO-PART-PR>
    <WS-TAG-NO-PART-SUF>BB5PM</WS-TAG-NO-PART-SUF>
    <WS-TAG-NOY/>   
</DU>        
  </RU>
```

Expected JSON OP:

```
        {  
       "json":{  
          "W1":"COA",   (HARDCODED)
          "W1":"02641",      HARDCODED
          "W3":"006",        HARDCODED
          "M1":"2019-02-15",
          "M2":"2019-02-16-01.35.15.906470",
          "P1":"1234",
          "P2":"ABC2",
          "P3":"PA",
          "P4":"", (MAP WS-TAG-NOY)
          }
          }
```

Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you doing the transformation? What language/environment do you use?

Comment: As I have mentioned , I have to transform using XSLT.

Comment: Look (with XSLT 3) into `xsl:map` and `xsl:map-entry` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#map-instructions and the `xsl:output method="json"`. XPath 3.1 also has a map data type https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#map-constructors. As for your samples, it is not clear why the second `DU` doesn't seem to contain any data to appear in the JSON result.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. As of now I am focusing on implementation part that how can I achieve the JSON format, I am not aware on writing the same in XSLT..After that will focus how to achieve For loop like condition... (to implement repeated element )..

Comment: @MartinHonnen - May I ask if you could you please guide me with more on implementation part.

Comment: XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 maps are the representation of JSON objects so construct a map as needed, then use `xsl:output` method="json"` and you transform XML to JSON. Example in two steps is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2W/ and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2W/1. Having some kind of repetition is a bit of a challenge as JSON arrays have an XPath 3.1 counterpart in XPath 3.1 arrays but the XSLT 3 spec does not have `xsl:array`/`xsl:array-member` instruction, Saxon PE or EE however have http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensions/instructions/array.html.

Comment: Thanks for sharing few examples. I have tried but giving me an error.below is the link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5Y

Comment: And which JSON do you expect that code to generate? Anyway, if you don't want to compute a JSON property name respectively the name of a XSLT `xsl:map-entry`, be aware that you need to quote the string for the name e.g. `<xsl:map-entry name="'foo'">...</xsl:map-entry>`. Some more examples in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2W/2.

Comment: Thanks.I will try to implement the same.